# How to use/bind mapDispatchToProps correctly in a container to call an action creator

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have issues in dispatching the functions from the ACTIONS in REACT-REDUX.

I have an 'action' (actions/index.js) below:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = 'sdfmbsjfsdf78fsdf78s78fs87f7s2bc5';
const ROOT_URL = `http://api.example.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city){
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},pk`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  console.log("Request in Actions: ", request); // this line is not showing in console because DISPATCHED action is not coming here

  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

And, I have a 'container' named 'SearchBar' (containers/SearchBar.js) in which 'mapDispatchToProps' has been written as:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import fetchWeather from '../actions/index';

class SearchBar extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = { term: '' };
  }

  onInputChange(event){
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  }
onFormSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.fetchWeather(this.state.term);
    this.setState({ term: ''});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <form onSubmit={ this.onFormSubmit.bind(this) } className="input-group">
        <input
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Search your favourite cities to get a five-day forecast"
          value={ this.state.term }
          onChange={ this.onInputChange.bind(this) }
          />
        <span className="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">Search</button>
        </span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchWeather: (city) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "FETCH_WEATHER"
      });
    }
  };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

**PROBLEM:**

My problem is: Whenever, I write some text in the **SEARCH BAR** and click on the **SEARCH** button in SearchBar.js, **mapDispatchToProps** is not firing the **fetchWeather** action from the actions/index.js file i.e. not witting to the console `console.log("Request in Actions: ", request);`.

**NOTE:** 
I needed to use latest mapDistpatchToProps only. This is also working `return bindActionCreators({fetchWeather}, dispatch);` But not looking for OLD stuffs.

Please, help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED following further debug (see comment)...

It looks like your `mapDispatchToProps` function should be:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchWeather: (city) => dispatch(fetchWeather(city))
  };
};
```

meaning that `this.props.fetchWeather(city)` is mapped to `dispatch(fetchWeather(city))` (your code misses the `fetchWeather` part in the second part of the mapping).

Then there's a problem in your import of `fetchWeather` because you haven't exported it as default but imported it as such. You could do one of two things:

1. add curly braces to your import to so it's not imported as
   default: `import { fetchWeather } from '../actions/index';`
2. export it as default: `export default function fetchWeather(city){...}`

I tested modification 1 and the action is dispatched.

<s>If not, you could investigate around your method binding (`onFormSubmit`, `onInputChange`), like trying the standard practice of having the binding done in the constructor.</s>

Comment: Thanks for replying. Such mapping gives such error: "Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _index2.default) is not a function"

Comment: @Owais Sorry: 1 - I mistyped my answer, there's an extra curly brace, this should have been: `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => { return { fetchWeather: (city) => dispatch(fetchWeather(city)) }; };` 2 - there's a problem with your import, you should have `import { fetchWeather } from '../actions/index';` (curly braces) because you don't export `fetchWeather` as default. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working. i accepted and upvoted. Thanks